# Can't find the MinGW binary parser

Tags: eclipse, windows, mingw

So I instaled MinGW for windows and followed all the instalation stepps untill the last one. which is instaling the binary parser. when I go to the list in eclipse I can't find the one that sais MinGW parser.

Does anybody know what's going on? normally I don't use eclipse but I want to try it because I also do my java programming in eclipse

Comment: I suggest you do your cross-compilation on a Linux virtual box. Windows is littered with problems, especially when mingw gets involved.

Comment: yeah I only have 10 gb 300kb/s of internet a month so I am really not looking forward having to download virtualbox and an ios if this can be fixed another way

Comment: VB and Linux + goodies are less than 1gig of space. I think it's worth the investment, considering the hell you'd have to go through otherwise.

Comment: yeah I just calculated how much time that would take that would take like 8 hours to download considering I often just drop down to 2kb/s for like an hour

Comment: so I don't think so dude. Irealy want to solve this windows wise

Comment: thanks bro, anything you know about this problem?

Comment: I'm going to turn @Sipty's advice on its head: if in the end you can't get MinGW to work, consider using the free version of Visual Studio, or the build tools from the Windows SDK.  You can invoke them from Eclipse, you don't need to use the VS IDE.  (This would still involve a sizable download, though, I'm afraid.)

Comment: I am not familiar with the specifics, but I have been a victim of mingw before. Notice how VLC recommends you cross-compile, rather than doing it natively: https://wiki.videolan.org/Win32Compile/

Comment: Regarding Harry's comment, I like it. I don't think it's suitable for open source projects though. But if you're working on a personal project, everything should be ok. SHOULD BE. :<